# SharePoint List Item View/Read Permission

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-list, nintex

I am actually new to SharePoint permissions stuff. I really need someone help to guide me or give me a hint.

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, with items. User create a item using Nintex forms and when item is created, Nintex Workflow get trigger.

The idea behind this list is, User A will create a item then User B will review it and approve/reject.
After User A create item, item permission should change to 'Read' so that user A doesn't change any value of item until user B take some action.

In Workflow, I am changing the item permission using 'Set Item Permission' action and setting permission as Read.

But the problem is:

1) After User A created item, he is not able to view/read item but able to edit item.
I selected item through list and click on 'view item' through ribbon, I am getting error 'Sorry, you don't have access to his page'.
I clicked on eclipse of item, selected Shared with->ADVANCED I am seeing the user A have view/read permission.
Then I made sure through 'Workflow history' if action got executed or not, it seems action got executed successfully.  [image]

This is really weird how user is able to edit item but not able to view item?

I really appreciate if anyone can provide any hint or help to make item readable.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, user with read access can't view list items. You can set up the list to only show items to their owner (Settings -> Advanced Settings and then set options for Read Access or Edit Access as "Only their own".

Please follow the below steps:

1. Please check Versioning Settings in List Settings, if you enable “Require content approval for submitted items” and the Approval Status of the list items is Pending / Rejected, users with read permission still can not see the items.
2. Make sure there is no filter of the view.
3. Make sure the user have read permission on the items. In other words, make sure the items of the list don’t have unique permissions.